# Which one is faster? Array Initialization or SIMD operations?

Tags: arrays, c, arm, initialization, neon

I need to use Neon Intrinsics (in `aarch64`) using slightly modified data from an array passed in a parameter of a function:

```c
void scenario1(uint16x8_t* X) {

    uint16x8_t arrayTest01[4] = {
          {X[0][4],X[0][5],X[0][6],X[0][7], -X[0][0],-X[0][1],-X[0][2],-X[0][3]},
          {X[1][4],X[1][5],X[1][6],X[1][7], -X[1][0],-X[1][1],-X[1][2],-X[1][3]},
          {X[2][4],X[2][5],X[2][6],X[2][7], -X[2][0],-X[2][1],-X[2][2],-X[2][3]},
          {X[3][4],X[3][5],X[3][6],X[3][7], -X[3][0],-X[3][1],-X[3][2],-X[3][3]}  
    };

    uint16x8_t arrayTest02[4];

    arrayTest02[0] = vextq_u16(X[0], vmulq_n_u16(X[0],-1),4);
    arrayTest02[1] = vextq_u16(X[1], vmulq_n_u16(X[1],-1), 4);
    arrayTest02[2] = vextq_u16(X[2], vmulq_n_u16(X[2],-1), 4);
    arrayTest02[3] = vextq_u16(X[3], vmulq_n_u16(X[3],-1), 4);

    // Rest of code which uses arrayTest01 and/or arrayTest02
}
```

The idea is that both `arrayTest01` and `arrayTest02` are lookup tables of data populated from an array of structures outside the `scenario1` function. The vectors in both `arrayTest01` and `arrayTest02` are half positive and half negative modulo 65536.

1. If I use `arrayTest01`, then the asm code does some ANDs and negations, but I'm unsure if that will be the case after compiling with -O3 (its hard to debug with -O3 and hit that breakpoint). I'm not sure if, when initializing, each element is loaded individually from memory or not.
2. The operation `vmulq_n_u16` multiplies by -1 (producing `-X[i]`), and `vextq_u16` extracts the upper half of `X[i]` and the lower half of `-X[i]`.
3. The operations `vmulq_n_u16` and `vextq_u16` should be executed in one cycle each, as they are SIMD, but still unsure if they are at the end faster or slower than just the initialization.

My concern is that both `arrayTest01` and `arrayTest02` will have thousands of entries and `scenario1` will be called multiple times, so any execution time / cycles count I can save would help greatly.

### Questions

1. Are the elements in the initialized array (`arrayTest01`) loaded from memory individually?
2. If so, are SIMD operations faster then?
3. In general, which would produce a faster execution time? The initialized array? or constructing the array using SIMD? (Again, the final arrays will have thousands of entries)

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try it out and measure which is fastest?

Comment: BTW: Have you profiled the code and made sure that exactly this part is the critical part?

Comment: Which architecture? `aarch32` or `aarch64`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE `aarch64`. I updated the question accordingly. Also, would different architectures make a difference here?

Comment: Yes, it does. `aarch32` compilers generate quite a mess when doing permutations.

Comment: btw, arrayTest02 seems to be flawed. It isn't identical to arrayTest01.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Fixed arrayTest01.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Based on your experience, which one do you think is faster? arrayTest01 or arrayTest02?

Comment: I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: Is this different from the last time you asked this?   also have you tried breaking them up into one dimentional arrays, working on this problem for this many months, I think you need to start trying other ideas or just live with the performance you get.  (or faster processor or bus or memory)

Comment: @old_timer huh? Has the OP been asking this several times already?

Comment: one other time, seems to be trying to optimize this, different exact question but under the same umbrella IMO

Comment: @old_timer I think it will stop since I provided the optimal answer :-)

Comment: @old_timer Last time it was static memory (hard-coded integer values), which had 0 expense when initialized, and was a comparison against different types of initialization. This time the values are populated from an array passed as a parameter in a function, and this time the question is initialization vs. SIMD.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Thank you for the response, definitely an out-of-the-box solution! I just don't quite get how to modify it in case I want 3 elements from the first array and 5 from the second, and not 4-4 like `arrayTest01`. Would an approach like that work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, 02 is faster **ONLY** because:

- Auto vectorization is VERY inefficient for 01 **in this case**
- The compilers seem to be rather gentle to 02 **in this case**

However, both are sub optimal.

How about this?

```
uint16x8_t arrayTest03[4];
int64x2x4_t temp, rslt;

temp = vld4q_s64((int64_t *)X);
rslt.val[0] = temp.val[1];
rslt.val[1] = vreinterpretq_s64_s16(vnegq_s16(vreinterpretq_s16_s64(temp.val[0])));
rslt.val[2] = temp.val[3];
rslt.val[3] = vreinterpretq_s64_s16(vnegq_s16(vreinterpretq_s16_s64(temp.val[2])));

vst4q_s64((int64_t *)arrayTest03, rslt);
```

Six instructions total.
You should think out of the box. Don't get tied to data types and short codes in C.
Especially, you should be explicit on memory load and store. You never know what kind of mess compilers generate.

BTW, all arrays should be aligned to 64bytes for maximum performance.

Comment: This is a really nice approach, definitely I learned something new today! Thank you! I have three questions: (1) You mention we have 6 instructions, but counting the `vld4q_s64` and `vst4q_s64` shouldn't be 8 in total? (2) This approach would only work if we group by 4s, i.e., an array of uint16x8_t of 4, as 64=16*4, right? (3) What if you want to have 3 values from the first array, and 5 from the second (and not 4 from the first and 4 from the second as I defined in `arrayTest01`)? I don't see you hard code any "4" anywhere? Thank you!

Comment: @liwuen Both `ld4` and `st4` are single instructions each.

Comment: I meant `vld4q_s64`+`vst4q_s64`+2(`vreinterpretq_s64_s16`+`vnegq_s16`+`vreinterpretq_s16_s64`)=2+2(3)=8 instructions?

Comment: Also can this approach be used if I want 3 values from the first array and 5 from the second? (and not 4 and 4)? This approach seems to work nicely as 4 divides 64, but 3 or 5 do not, or am I wrong?

Comment: @liwuen Why don't you look at the disassembly? As for the latter question, that's a completely different problem. I'd transpose the 2d array, and negate vector5, vector6, and vector7, re-transpose and store. Take a look at `vld4_lane_s16` and `vst4_lane_s16`.